# I need to have a input box using Angular.js whose value is dependent on a formula

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive

I need to have a input box using Angular.js whose value is dependent on a formula  that includes the value of another text field.

Now if I have a value for Field A, then value of Field B should be evaluated, also it should allow the editing of Field B with a value independent of the formula.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clearly understanding what you mean. I assume you have 2 inputs A and B. Input B value dependent on input A . In that case you create a **switch/ng-change** function to input A. If you want inputB to be non-editable, add read-only attribute to input field

//by using watch

`$scope.$watch('inputA',function(new,old){
   $scope.inputB = new; // do whatever computation you want
});`

//by using ng-change

`$scope.onChangeOfInputA = function (){
   $scope.inputB = new; // do whatever computation you want
}`

Comment: Thanks Gopinath, U got that right however I want Input field B to be editable as well and accept any new value which the user enters manually for it... can u help me with that too?